# Dynamically changing content of ContentControl via trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I need to flip between two views dynamically based on a boolean flag in my ViewModel.

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">

            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource View1}" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowingView2}">                                     
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource View2}" />                                   
                </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>

         </Style>
     </ContentControl.Style>
 </ContentControl>
```

However, `View2` never gets displayed, even if `IsShowingView2` is always true.

Any ideas anyone? All the examples I can find seem to be altering the ContentTemplate instead, but I have no need to do that. I just want different content.

Comment: Check the Visual Studio Output Window to see if you have Binding Errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually setting a value for the `DataTrigger`

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowingView2}" Value="True">                                     
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource View2}" />                                   
</DataTrigger>
```

Also check for binding errors in the output window.

Comment: OMG! I can't believe I did that. Been messing around with templates for the last 45 mins! Thanks a million.

Comment: I did this exact same thing last week, the Output window is really great for this.